# Evaluate limit using L'Hospital

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x^{30})}{\sin^{30}(5x)} $

I have tried applying L'Hospital's rule, but it took me a lot of time to factor the derivative. Is there any way can resolve this problem. Thanks.

The answer is $\frac{1}{5^{30}}$ but my result is 1.

Comment: Do you know that $\lim \limits _{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x} {x} =1$? If yes then write the expression under limit as $\dfrac{\sin x^{30}}{x^{30}}\cdot\dfrac{x^{30}}{(5x)^{30}} \left(\dfrac{5x}{\sin 5x}\right)^{30}$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you! That would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor series so you don't have to differentiate $30$ times. We have $\sin(t)=t-\frac16t^3+\cdots$. Inserting $t=x^{30}$ gives us the numerator, and inserting $t=5x$ and raising the result to the power of $30$ gives the denominator:
$$
\frac{\sin(x^{30})}{\sin^{30}(5x)}=\frac{x^{30}-\frac13x^{90}+\cdots}{(5x)^{30}-30\cdot\frac16(5x)^{32}+\cdots}
$$
Now divide both the numerator and the denominator by $x^{30}$, and the limit will be much easier to compute.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ approaches zero $\sin x^{30}$ is equivalent to $x^{30}.

Also $\sin ^{30} 5x$ is equivalent to $(5x)^{30}$ thus the ratio approaches $\frac {1}{5^{30}}$

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is with equivalents: near $0$, $\sin u\sim u$, so
$$\frac{\sin(x^{30})}{\sin^{30}(5x)}\sim_0\frac{x^{30}}{(5x)^{30}}=\frac1{5^{30}}.$$